# active .user.ini for one user

Tags: php, .htaccess

I active custom user php.ini . now user's can have their own .user.ini.
now i want some of my user use this feature and other deny from using custom .user.ini

so i uncomment line :

; To disable this feature set this option to empty value
user_ini.filename =

now this feature is disable for all user, how can i active it for user1 not all of them(exm) ?
server is LAMP with no panel of course

CentOs 6.x apache + SUphp FaCGI

I used this directive in virtual host but it didn't work

```
DocumentRoot /home/mam/public_html
ServerName mam.test.ir
suPHP_Engine on
suPHP_UserGroup mam mam
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php 
php_value user_ini.filename  ".user.ini"
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/mam/public_html
```

is there any idea ?????? **NOTE: I don't want to use .htaccess for this**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself :|

For doing this you have to way one is include file and second is:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/mam/public_html/php.ini
```

You need to use absolute path :)

Answer (score 0):

A trick could be to use CHMOD to make the .user.ini in the specific virtual host document root readable and writable only to the admin/root user (feature disabled) or to the user too (feature enabled).